# Is there an R function for plotting my x variable (months) against multiple y variables?

Tags: r

I managed to get the plot that I want by manually typing in the commands, but I failed to change the x-axis from numerical scale to categorical variables which are months (Jan-Dec). Please assist with commands I can use to replicate the plot below from imported data, csv format?

```
mydata <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)
Y1 <- c(20, 18, 40, 54, 63, 63, 59, 72, 64, 60, 46, 44 )
Y2 <- c(16, 32, 89, 87, 64, 64, 39, 36, 29, 55, 58, 46 )
Y3 <- c(46, 39, 43, 67, 45, 37, 13, 11, 38, 59, 53, 47 )
Y4 <- c(32, 41, 45, 43, 62, 69, 94, 66, 62, 58, 87, 34 )
Y5 <- c(51, 31, 91, 99, 37, 62, 12, 30, 65, 59, 72, 44 )
plot(mydata, Y2010, type="l", col="#FF0000", pch="*", lty=1, ylim=c(0,100), xlab = "Months", ylab="Y %" )
points(mydata, Y2011, col="#FFFF00", pch="*")
lines(mydata, Y2011, col="#FFFF00",lty=1)
points(mydata, Y2012, col="#00FF00",pch="*")
lines(mydata, Y2012, col="#00FF00",lty=1)
points(mydata, Y2013, col="#0000FF", pch="*")
lines(mydata, Y2013, col="#0000FF",lty=1)
points(mydata, Y2014, col="#00FFFF", pch="*")
lines(mydata, Y2014, col="#00FFFF",lty=1)
points(mydata, Y2015, col="#FF00FF", pch="*")
lines(mydata, Y2015, col="#FF00FF",lty=1)
legend("topleft", c("2010","2011","2012","2013","2014","2015"), col=c("#FF0000","#FFFF00","#00FF00","#0000FF","#00FFFF","#FF00FF"),
   pch=c("*","*","*","*","*"),lty=c(1,2,3,1,2), ncol=1, cex = 0.5)
```

[I want my x-axis to range from Jan to Dec instead of 1 to 12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s07JD.png)

Comment: The code gives an error as several variables were not defined.

Comment: For me, the code runs okay without errors. I'm not sure why it gives you errors.

Comment: I ran that on rStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `ggplot2` approach (Updated):

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
mydata <- factor(format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=12, by='1 month'),'%b'),
                 levels = format(seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), length.out=12, by='1 month'),'%b'),
                 ordered = T)
Y1 <- c(20, 18, 40, 54, 63, 63, 59, 72, 64, 60, 46, 44 )
Y2 <- c(16, 32, 89, 87, 64, 64, 39, 36, 29, 55, 58, 46 )
Y3 <- c(46, 39, 43, 67, 45, 37, 13, 11, 38, 59, 53, 47 )
Y4 <- c(32, 41, 45, 43, 62, 69, 94, 66, 62, 58, 87, 34 )
Y5 <- c(51, 31, 91, 99, 37, 62, 12, 30, 65, 59, 72, 44 )
#Create data
df <- data.frame(mydata,Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4,Y5)
#Melt
df.melted <- melt(df,id.vars = 'mydata')
#plot
ggplot(df.melted,aes(x=factor(mydata),y=value,color=variable,group=variable))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line()+
  scale_color_manual(labels=c(2011:2015),values = c('red','blue','green','pink','orange'))+
  xlab('Year')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but I want the x-axis scale to range from Jan to Dec, which is not numerical. That way it will be easier for my audience to understand the graph

Comment: @MisBlearnsR I have updated the solution considering what you want. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: @MisBlearnsR Great, if you feel comfortable with this answer you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side of this answer :)

Comment: I did, thanks. But why do I get this error when I run it again after editing? "Error: Cannot add ggproto objects together. Did you forget to add this object to a ggplot object?"

Comment: @MisBlearnsR You must be missing some `+` symbol when adding elements to the main `ggplot`. Just check that!

Comment: @MisBlearnsR I have run the code in the solution and works fine, did you use other data?